# How to load CSV file with records on multiple lines?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.3.0.

As a Apache Spark's project I am using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stacksample) data set to work on. When trying to read csv using spark, row in spark dataframe does not corresponds to correct row in csv (See sample csv [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/122DGn22xkMKGLN65X8cIGHgxyNRZcSfpA4kpIU_atjo/edit?usp=sharing)) file. Code looks like following:

```
answer_df = sparkSession.read.csv('./stacksample/Answers_sample.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True, multiLine=True);
answer_df.show(2)
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
|                  Id|  OwnerUserId|        CreationDate|ParentId|Score|                Body|
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
|                  92|           61|2008-08-01T14:45:37Z|      90|   13|"<p><a href=""htt...|
|<p>A very good re...| though.</p>"|                null|    null| null|                null|
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

However,
When i used pandas, it worked like a charm.

```
df = pd.read_csv('./stacksample/Answers_sample.csv')
df.head(3)
```

**Output**

```
Index Id    OwnerUserId CreationDate    ParentId    Score   Body
0   92  61  2008-08-01T14:45:37Z    90  13  <p><a href="http://svnbook.red-bean.com/">Vers...
1   124 26  2008-08-01T16:09:47Z    80  12  <p>I wound up using this. It is a kind of a ha...
```

**My Observation:**
Apache spark is treating every line in csv file as a record for dataframe( which is reasonable) but on the other hand, pandas intelligently ( not sure based on which parameters) figures out where the record end actually.

**Question**
I would like to know, how can i instruct Spark to load the dataframe properly.

The data to be loaded is as follows with the lines starting with `92` and `124` being two records.

```
Id,OwnerUserId,CreationDate,ParentId,Score,Body
92,61,2008-08-01T14:45:37Z,90,13,"<p><a href=""http://svnbook.red-bean.com/"">Version Control with Subversion</a></p>

<p>A very good resource for source control in general. Not really TortoiseSVN specific, though.</p>"
124,26,2008-08-01T16:09:47Z,80,12,"<p>I wound up using this. It is a kind of a hack, but it actually works pretty well. The only thing is you have to be very careful with your semicolons. : D</p>

<pre><code>var strSql:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);      
var i:Number = 0;
var strSqlSplit:Array = strSql.split("";"");
for (i = 0; i &lt; strSqlSplit.length; i++){
    NonQuery(strSqlSplit[i].toString());
}
</code></pre>
"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I *think* you should use `option("escape", "\"")` as it seems that `"` is used as so-called [quote escape characters](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers#escaping-quote-escape-characters).

```
val q = spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true)
  .option("header", true)
  .option("escape", "\"")
  .csv("input.csv")
scala> q.show
+---+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
| Id|OwnerUserId|        CreationDate|ParentId|Score|                Body|
+---+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
| 92|         61|2008-08-01T14:45:37Z|      90|   13|<p><a href="http:...|
|124|         26|2008-08-01T16:09:47Z|      80|   12|<p>I wound up usi...|
+---+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 12):

After few hours of struggle I was able to figure out the solution.

**Analysis:**
Data dump provided by `Stackoverflow` had `quote(")` being escaped by a another `quote(")`. And since spark uses `slash(\)` as default value for escape character, which i was not passing, therefore it end up in giving meaningless output.

**Updated code**

```
answer_df = sparkSession.read.\
    csv('./stacksample/Answers_sample.csv', 
        inferSchema=True, header=True, multiLine=True, escape='"');

answer_df.show(2)
```

Note the use of `escape` parameter in `csv()`.

**Output**

```
+---+-----------+-------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
| Id|OwnerUserId|       CreationDate|ParentId|Score|                Body|
+---+-----------+-------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
| 92|         61|2008-08-01 20:15:37|      90|   13|<p><a href="http:...|
|124|         26|2008-08-01 21:39:47|      80|   12|<p>I wound up usi...|
+---+-----------+-------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
```

Hope it will help other and save some time for them.

Comment: Doh! Looks like we've got it at the same time! :)

Comment: I will be accepting your answer, but will keep mine as well as I have added some basic analysis as well ( it may help other understand)

Comment: I was about to write _"Please accept your answer and I'll delete mine."_ but your generosity has greatly influenced my decision :)