# Pandas dataframe and spark dataframe return different number of rows when loading the same .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to load the same .csv file (~601MB) to a pandas dataframe as well as a spark dataframe. Doing a simple row count on both dataframes gives different number of rows:

- pandas: 2,206,990
- spark: 3,738,937

I'm using a spark cluster (i3.xlarge 30.5GB memory + 3 workers of same type) on Databricks. And also tried to use an AWS EC2 instance for loading the pandas dataframe (i3.xlarge 30.5GB memory).
The file is loaded in spark as below:

```
train_df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").csv(train_pth, header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

In pandas:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv(train_pth, delimiter=";")
```

I'm new to pandas. Could anyone please advise if pandas `read_csv` function imposes a limit on the number of rows to load?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `pd.read_csv` has an `nrows` option to read the first `nrows`, but by default it's `None`. You could try setting it to 4,000,000 but, the issue might be from how the csv is formatted. Are there null rows, or anything particularly special about the extra rows that spark loads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load CSV file with records on multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188579/how-to-load-csv-file-with-records-on-multiple-lines)